# I keep getting the same error in my error logs on my apache server using cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

```
cPanel Version  11.28.87
Theme   x3
Apache version  1.3.42
PHP version     5.2.13
MySQL version   5.0.92-community
Architecture    i686
Operating system    linux
```

I noticed in the Error Log that I was getting the same error repeatedly. A simple missing .gif that was being requested.

```
[Tue Apr 12 12:12:23 2011] [error] [client --.---.---.---] File does not exist: /public_html/themes/3col_blue/images/dogcat.gif
```

So I thought well lets just put that .gif (our logo) there...

Now I am getting a whole slew of errors regarding file does not exist that look like this:

```
[Tue Apr 12 02:27:47 2011] [error] [client --.---.---.---] File does not exist: /home/--------/public_html/index.php+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+\xe8\xf1\xef\xee\xeb\xfc\xe7\xee\xe2\xe0\xed+\xed\xe8\xea\xed\xe5\xe9\xec+"reltWeiweessy";+\xe7\xe0\xf0\xe5\xe3\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf0\xe8\xf0\xee\xe2\xe0\xeb\xe8\xf1\xfc+(\xe2\xea\xeb\xfe\xf7\xe5\xed+\xf0\xe5\xe6\xe8\xec+\xf2\xee\xeb\xfc\xea\xee+\xf0\xe5\xe3\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf0\xe0\xf6\xe8\xe8);
[Tue Apr 12 02:27:42 2011] [error] [client --.---.---.---] File does not exist: /home/--------/public_html/index.php+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Result:+\xe8\xf1\xef\xee\xeb\xfc\xe7\xee\xe2\xe0\xed+\xed\xe8\xea\xed\xe5\xe9\xec+"reltWeiweessy";+\xe7\xe0\xf0\xe5\xe3\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf0\xe8\xf0\xee\xe2\xe0\xeb\xe8\xf1\xfc+(\xe2\xea\xeb\xfe\xf7\xe5\xed+\xf0\xe5\xe6\xe8\xec+\xf2\xee\xeb\xfc\xea\xee+\xf0\xe5\xe3\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf0\xe0\xf6\xe8\xe8);
```

how did I make this go from bad to worse?

Comment: Please note that while it is surely not the cause of these errors, Apache 1.x has reached end of life and is no longer supported.

Comment: Server Upgraded! Thanks for the suggestion. Now we are Apache version  2.2.17

Answer (score 0):

Are there referers for those particular hits in the access_log? Looks like someone/something is pointing at your site with a badly constructed link.

Comment: I found that this site was part of a backlink farm before i got here... So poorly constructed links seems like a strong candidate. Now how to fix... @ Marc B

Comment: Not much you can do. Maybe have some fun and serve up a goatse-type image to anyone requesting one of those images.